# Meta Query with spaces in value?

Tags: loop, meta-query

Im using meta query to filter a post loop...

```
'meta_query'     => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'some_key',
            'value'   => 'some value here', #single word values work
            'compare' => 'IN'
        )
```

the loop works if the value is one word, but if it has spaces it doesn't, how can I get this working?

Thank you!

Comment: That query is going to be super expensive, storing that data in a custom taxonomy would have been thousands of times faster

Comment: There is nothing I can do about that, its part of a plugin we use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pass your multi value in array, example

```
'meta_query'     => array(
    array(
        'key'     => 'some_key',
        'value'   => array(
           "value1 with space",
           "value2",
           "value3",
        ),
        'compare' => 'IN'
    )
```